# React hook Search on button click not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get a list of repositories using GitHub API, search has to work on button click and on change selectBox with licences

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import { Layout } from "./../Layout";
import { List } from "./../List";
import { Loader } from "./../Loader";
import { Header } from "./../Header";
import { Search } from "./../Search";
import { Licenses } from "./../Licenses";

import "./App.css";

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [nameSearch, setNameSearch] = useState("");
  const [license, setLicense] = useState({});

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    setHasError(false);
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const prevMonth = moment()
        .subtract(30, "days")
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD");

      const licenseKey = (license && license.key) || "";

      const response = await axios(
        `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${nameSearch}+in:name+language:javascript+created:${prevMonth}${
          licenseKey ? `+license:${licenseKey}` : ""
        }&sort=stars&order=desc`
      );
      setData(response.data.items);
    } catch (error) {
      setHasError(true);
      setData([]);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [license]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Header>
        <Search
          handleSearchChange={setNameSearch}
          nameSearch={nameSearch}
          isLoading={isLoading}
          onSearch={fetchData}
        />
        <Licenses license={license} handleLicenseChange={setLicense} />
      </Header>

      <main>
        {hasError && <div>Error</div>}

        {isLoading ? <Loader /> : <List data={data} />}
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

First of all, I get warning
*Compiled with warnings.

./src/components/App/App.js

  Line 42:6:  React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'nameSearch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps*

And my search is not working because `nameSearch` is always empty in the query string.

How to make search work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding nameSearch to the list of dependencies for useCallback:

```
const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
  ...
}, [license, nameSearch]);
```

and make sure setNameSearch is actually used inside `Search.js` so that it will have a value.

Comment: No, this code will send the request on every `nameSearch` change, but I don't need this. I need to send the request only on Button click.

Comment: Ok, in this case I suggest not to use useCallback, but a simple function:
`const fetchData = async () => { ... }`
and pass it to Search.js as onSubmit, calling this whenever the button gets clicked.

Comment: Wow, thank, it works! But I get the warning `Line 47:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. Do I need to fix it somehow?

Comment: Great, now you can remove `[fetchData]` from the list of useEffect dependencies, I think, as it's not a hook anymore.

Comment: Yes, I've already done that. But I also need to call `fetchData` on searchName clear, i tried `const handleNameSearchChange = value => {
    setNameSearch(value);
    if (!value) fetchData();
  };` but fecthData is called before setNameSearch changes state. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: In his case I suggest to add a useCallback with nameSearch as a dependency and in there call fetchData if nameSearch is empty.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? I need to call `fetchData()` in three cases: on searchButton click, on licence change and on searchName change if searchName  is empty and I don't know how to make all three work